# Re-install Instance Microsoft SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server

I delete by mistake one of the instances in MSSQL.

[image]

Is there a way to re-install the instance so I can connect to my local DB or is there a way to retrieve the content of that database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling an instance does not delete user databases.You should be fine reinstalling the instance and reattach the mdf,ldf files.

Here is a refference of what uninstalling an instance does.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/uninstall-an-existing-instance-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=Windows10